# Nested Lambdas in wxHaskell Library

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I've been trying to figure out how I can make staticText elements resize to fit their contents with wxHaskell. From what I can tell, this is the default behavior in wxWidgets, but the wxHaskell wrapper specifically disables this behavior. However, the library code that creates new elements has me very confused. Can anyone provide an explanation for what this code does?

```
staticText :: Window a -> [Prop (StaticText ())] -> IO (StaticText ())
staticText parent props
  = feed2 props 0 $
    initialWindow $ \id rect ->
    initialText   $ \txt -> \props flags ->
    do t <- staticTextCreate parent id txt rect flags {- (wxALIGN_LEFT + wxST_NO_AUTORESIZE) -}
       set t props
       return t
```

I know that `feed2 x y f = f x y`, and that the type signature of initialWindow is

```
initialWindow :: (Id -> Rect -> [Prop (Window w)] -> Style -> a) -> [Prop (Window w)] -> Style -> a
```

and the signature of initialText is

```
initialText :: Textual w => (String -> [Prop w] -> a) -> [Prop w] -> a
```

but I just can't wrap my head around all the lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, everything is nested lambdas! `\txt -> \props flags -> do {...}` is the same as `\txt props flags -> do {...}`, both are actually short forms of

```
\txt -> \props -> \flags -> do {...}
```

What's a bit confusing here is that `\txt props flags` seem to be to many arguments:

```
initialText :: ...=> (String -> [Prop w] -> a) -> ...
```

appears to take a 2-argument function, and we give it a three-parameter lambda. But remember: *actually*, every function takes only **one** argument, everything else is done by currying. In this case, `a` is again a function type, so it should actually read rather

```
initialText :: Textual w => (String -> [Prop w] -> b -> c) -> [Prop w] -> b -> c
```

That's not the end of fun. The argument to `initialWindow` seems to have to *little* parameters, 2 instead of 4, but that's again not the case: we have only given `initialWindow` its first argument, the result is a function that accepts more arguments first the `[Prop w]` one (in this case, `[Prop(Window w)]` in `initialWindow`'s signature). Then it gives back `a`, which we re-wrote as `b->c`; in this case what `initialWindow` needs is `Style -> a`.

So the actual signature of `initialText` in this application would be

```
(String -> [Prop(Window w)] -> Style -> c) -> [Prop w] -> Style -> c
```

Comment: So how is `flags` getting set? Is it the 0 passed to `feed2`?

Comment: initialText :: (String -> [Prop(Window w)] -> Style -> IO (StaticText ())) -> [Prop w] -> Style -> IO (StaticText ())

Comment: @kunkelwe: 'flags' is a parameter of the function which is the first parameter passed to 'initialWindow'.  So 'flags' is set when 'initialWindows' calls its first parameter and passes value that becomes bound to the 'flags' parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The WX library, which I have not used, seems to use a strange callback or continuation passing style internally.   And this shadows `props` in a confusing way, let me rename that sucker:

```
staticText1 :: Window a -> [Prop (StaticText ())] -> IO (StaticText ())
staticText1 parent propsTopLevel
  = feed2 propsTopLevel 0 $
    initialWindow $ \id rect ->
    initialText   $ \txt -> \propsParam flags ->
    do t <- staticTextCreate parent id txt rect flags
       set t propsParam
       return t
```

Without ($) I can use parenthesis:

staticText2 :: Window a -> [Prop (StaticText ())] -> IO (StaticText ())
staticText2 parent propsTopLevel
  = feed2 propsTopLevel 0 (initialWindow (\id rect ->
      initialText  (\txt -> \propsParam flags -> do
        t <- staticTextCreate parent id txt rect flags
        set t props
        return t)))

The lambdas such as `\text -> \props flags ->` can be named:

```
staticText3 :: Window a -> [Prop (StaticText ())] -> IO (StaticText ())
staticText3 parent propsTopLevel = initialWindow myWindow propsTopLevel 0
  where makeWindow id rect = initialText myText
          where myText txt propsParam flags = do
                  t <- staticTextCreate parent id txt rect flags
                  set t propsParam
                  return t
```

In the `staticText3` I used nested lexical scope for the parameter name.  Let me make that a bit more explicit:

```
staticText4 :: Window a -> [Prop (StaticText ())] -> IO (StaticText ())
staticText4 = makeWindowTextStatic where
  makeWindowTextStatic parent propsTopLevel = initialWindow (makeTextStatic parent) propsTopLevel 0
  makeTextStatic parent id rect = initialText (makeStatic parent id rect)
  makeStatic parent id rect txt propsParam flags = do
    t <- staticTextCreate parent id txt rect flags
    set t propsParam
    return t
```

Is this clear enough to follow the flow?  I have not tried to understand the `initialWindow` and `initialText` themselves, yet.